# CS50x Pset 2 Readability: Why are L and S not correctly calculated?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm working on this problem: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/readability/

Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    // L = (letters in total) / (words in total) * 100
    // S = (sentences in total) / (words in total) * 100

    int letters = 0; // amount of letters contained in the text.
    int sentences = 0; // amount of sentences in the text.
    int words = 0; // amount of words in the text.
    float L;
    float S;
    float grade;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++) // loop through each letter in this txt.
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 65 && text[i] <= 90) || (text[i] >= 97 && text[i] <= 122)) // check if the current byte is a letter.
        {
            letters++;
        }
        else if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?') // check if the current byte is the end mark of the sentence.
        {
            sentences++;
        }
        else if (text[i] == ' ') // check if the current byte is a space.
        {
            words++;
        }
    }

    L = (float) letters / (float) words * 100;
    S = (float) sentences / (float) words * 100;
    grade = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

    printf("L = %f, S = %f\n", L, S);
    printf("letters: %i\n", letters);
    printf("words: %i\n", words + 1);
    printf("sentences: %i\n", sentences);
    printf("grade: %f\n", grade);
}
```

I think that my code is logically correct, and I can't tell any difference compared to others. However, there's trouble when I tried to get the value of L and S which are presented just like below:

```
L = (float) letters / (float) words * 100;
S = (float) sentences / (float) words * 100;
```

With the sample input sentence

> Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places!
> You're off and away!

the variable *letters* and *words* are supposed to be 65 and 14, therefore

```
L = (float) 65 / (float) 14 * 100;
```

The correct answer should be 464.2, but instead, I got 500.0.

- I have tried to replace the variable name with the actual value, the answer was correct.
- I have also tried this following new code and I got the correct answer.

> ```
> #include <cs50.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
> int main(void)
> {
>     int a = 65;
>     int b = 14;
>     float c = (float) a / (float) b * 100;
>     printf("%f\n", c);
>     printf("%f\n", (float) a);
>     printf("%f\n", (float) b);
>     printf("%f\n", (float) a / (float) b);
> }
> ```

Please help! I really don't know how to figure the issues out!

Comment: Can you please include a log of the output of running the program?

Comment: Have you tried printing `letters` and `sentences` to see if they contain what you expect?

Comment: I don't quite know how to use this platform properly, so I didn't see you guys commenting in the first place, now I have done this right, thank you for your kind reply!!!

Comment: Don't edit your question to add "solved". You should mark one of the posted answers as "accepted" if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not counting the last word in the last sentence, since there's no space after it.

Add

```
words++;
```

after the end of the loop to count the last word.

And since you're adding 1 there, you don't need to use `words + 1` when printing the number of words.

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for commenting! Actually, my code is based on assuming that there is a space after each end mark in the text, so the final results of sentences, words, letters are all correct. I printed and checked them at the end of the code. My question is, why am I getting the wrong result while having all variables correctly? (Sorry if my English was hard to read or confusing.)

Comment: There's no space after the last end mark, so you're not counting the last word.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I realized the issue and solved the problem.